# Showing a DialogFragment object from an on click inside a button listener

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I was just trying showing a DialogFragment object from an on click inside a button listener.

Here is the code of the activity that should start the Dialog:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerToButton1();
}

private void addListenerToButton1(){
    final Context context = this;


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            DP ciao = new DP();
            ciao.show(this,"MyDP");
        }
    });
}
}
```

And here's the code of the Dialog:

```
public class DP extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setMessage("Prova")
    .setPositiveButton("POS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("NEG", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Errors are:

- The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String)
- The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String)

Any advice?

Comment: plz show your updated code you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29) DialogFragment.show also accept FragmentManager instance as first parameter

Comment: Here is the updated code:

      button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
    DP ciao = new DP();
     ciao.show(MainActivity.this.getFragmentManager(),"MyDP");
   }
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method of passing the correct context into your DialogFragment

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        DP ciao = new DP();
        ciao.show(view.getContext(),"MyDP");
    }
});
```

In your original code, when calling

```
'ciao.show(this,"MyDP");'
```

the this refers to its parent class which is OnClickListener.

When assigning a click listener and overriding the onClick, you get passed the view and an argument which you can use to access information from, including the context.

Comment: On the line of the show method error is: view cannot be resolved

Comment: Did you change onClick(View arg0) to onClick(View view) ?

Comment: Yes, error now is: The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (Context, 
 String)

Comment: You can try using 'public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity' instead of 'public class MainActivity extends Activity'

Comment: Then call 'FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager()' before calling the show and pass fm into show as the first argument. 'ciao.show(fm,"MyDP")'

Comment: If you are using the android support library you would extend from android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and call getSupportFragmentManager() instead...

Comment: Ok got it. But had to do this: android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); and then passed the fm as first parameter in show. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here is a good resource for future dialogfragment adventures: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 2):

Show `DialogFragment` from Activity by passing `FragmentManager` instance for interacting with fragments associated with current activity  as instead of by passing Activity or Button Context:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        DialogFragment ciao = DP.newInstance();
        ciao.show(MainActivity.this.getFragmentManager(),"MyDP");
    }
});
```

and you will also need to add following `newInstance()` method in DP `DialogFragment` which return you DialogFragment instance :

```
public static DP newInstance() {
        DP frag = new DP();
        return frag;
    }
```

Comment: Doing what you said error is: -The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)

Comment: ok. did it. Error occours on this line:
    DialogFragment ciao = DP.newInstance();

Error is:
The method newInstance() is undefined for the type DP

Comment: Always on line that contains DialogFragment ciao = DP.newInstance(); occours an error of convertion: Type mismatch: cannot convert from DP to DialogFragment

Answer (score 1):

Extend your fragment (DP) from the android.app.DialogFragment

you can access `FragmentManager` from within `Activity` by `getFragmentManager()`

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        DP ciao = new DP();
        ciao.show(getFragmentManager(),"MyDP");
    }
});
```

Hopefully this works :)